# jQuery animations are choppy on firefox with transparent gradients. Any fallback?

Tags: jquery, css

I designed a page with lot of transparency. and a few parts of it use semi-transparent CSS3 gradients.
Now these gradients work fine but firefox has a problem with them and jQuery.
If there is a semi-transparent CSS3 gradient, most jQuery animations on the page become choppy.

Is there any jQuery way to generate Gradient? will that help remove the choppiness from animations in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SVG Gradients](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_gradients.html) or a jQuery plugin like [this one](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1014-Creating-Transparent-Gradients-With-jQuery.htm).